# Python MultiThreading - Parallel, joblib

Tags: python, python-multithreading

```
import json
import os
import glob
import time
from vectorGen import myFunction
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

directory_path = '/home/WikiFiles/input'
output_path = '/home/WikiFiles/vectorOutput'

file_name = '*'

**#Method to add vector to the given JSON.**
def addVector(sourceObject):
    start_time = time.time()

    if ('content' in sourceObject):
        vector = myFunction(sourceObject['content'], sourceObject['title'])
    else:
        vector = myFunction(sourceObject['title'])
    end_time = time.time()
    sourceObject['vector'] = vector
    sourceObject['vec_time'] = (end_time - start_time) * 1000

**#Method to process each line of JSONFile to add vectors**
def processJSONFile(json_file):
    file_name = os.path.basename(json_file)
    print(file_name)
    output_file_path = output_path + "/" + file_name

    with open(output_file_path, 'w') as out_file:
        with open(json_file, 'r') as input_file:
            for line in input_file:
                try:
                    sourceObject = json.loads(line)
                    addVector(sourceObject)
                    out_file.write(json.dumps(sourceObject))
                    out_file.write("\n")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

**# Use glob to find all JSON files in the directory**
json_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, file_name + '.json'))
print("Files", len(json_files))

**#Dividing the files into multuiple chunks of 33 files**
file_chunks = [json_files[i:i + 33] for i in range(0, len(json_files), 33)]

results = []

# Process each chunk of files with 33 threads using parallel from joblib
for chunk in file_chunks:
    chunk_results = Parallel(n_jobs=33)(delayed(processJSONFile)(json_file) for json_file in chunk)
    results.extend(chunk_results)
```

The input folder has 1000s of files. To process those files faster, divided those files into multiple chunks of 33 files, and then processed the chunks one by one. Processing files within the chunk in parallel using Parallel command in joblib library.

But after processing the first chunk of 33 files, the process terminates. Processing of the next chunks is not started.  CentOS Linux 7. Python 3.9